# How do i save the current frame/image in pictureBox1 to a bitmap file?

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

In the top of Form1 I did: `Bitmap bmp;` In the paint event I'm drawing to the `pictureBox` and also to the `bmp` file:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush brush;
    Pen p = null;
    Point connectionPointStart;
    Point connectionPointEnd;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    Graphics bitmapGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    //g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    moveCounter++;
    label6.Text = moveCounter.ToString();

    brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    p = new Pen(brush);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < wireObject1._point_X.Count; ++idx)
    {
        Point dPoint = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[idx], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[idx]);
        dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
        dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
        g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
        bitmapGraphics.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

        // g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
    {
        int startIndex = wireObject1._connectionstart[i];
        int endIndex = wireObject1._connectionend[i];

        connectionPointStart = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[startIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[startIndex]);
        connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[endIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[endIndex]);
        p.Width = 2;
        g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
        bitmapGraphics.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
    }
}
```

I did a new instance in the paint event for the bmp file. I also make a new graphics variable for the bmp file. And every place i draw or fill ellipse to the pictureBox I also draw it to the bmp file.

Now in the save function I did:

```
private void SavePictureBoxToBitmap()
{
    //PbToBitmap++;
    //String tempFile = @"d:\PictureBoxToBitmap\" + PbToBitmap.ToString("D6") + bmp;
    bmp.Save(@"d:\PictureBoxToBitmap\bit.bmp");
}
```

If im doing bmp.Save it will save to the hard disk a white bmp file with the drawings inside only. If im doing pictureBox1.Image.Save it will save to the hard disk a file with the picture in the pictureBox only without the drawings.

How can i combine it so i will make one save line/command and it will create one bmp file on the hard disk with the pictureBox image and the drawings together?

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions to `D:\`? (Would it happen to be a CD drive?)

Comment: minitech D: is my second hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to draw something onto an Image, create a Graphics element using the static function FromBitmap:

```
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image)
```

Then you draw things on the picture box by using the gfx instance, e.g. gfx.DrawLine.

Then to save it, use the pictureBox1.Image.Save function.

**UPDATE**

Your code is a bit too cryptic for me, but I made a simple example which might answer your question. I created a newq empty form, added a picture box, and then implemented the Paint function.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), new Point(10, 10), new Point(20, 20));
        gfx.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), new Point(20, 10), new Point(10, 20));
        pictureBox1.Image.Save("test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox1.Refresh(); // The file will be correct without this, but the update will not be shown
    }
```

Comment: Ok adding \ to this: String tempFile = @"d:\PictureBoxToBitmap" like:  String tempFile = @"d:\PictureBoxToBitmap\"  now its saving the images/frames as i wanted but without the points that i have added/drawed on the pictureBox . I need to save also the things that are drawed not only the pictureBox1.Image

Comment: Made an example, as you can see in the post above. I hope it will atleast get you a little further.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height))
{
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save("output.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Should work

Comment: Please try to elaborate on code-only answers. Explain why your answer is better than the others, or what it offers that's different from the others. Also be aware that this question is over 4 years old.